# QT: When to use QT::keyRelease

Tags: unit-testing, qt, keypress, qtestlib, keyrelease

I'm writing a test app that tests another application with a bunch of menus. I simulate keyPresses by using QT::keyPress. However, at some point it doesn't accept keyPresses anymore, until I learned you need to use keyRelease as well (according to the documentation which was a bit vague for me, it says "Note: At some point you should release the key using keyRelease()."  --- but when? right after each keyPress?)

Calling a keyRelease after each keyPress simulates a keyPress as well which is weird. 
Calling keyRelease once after the very first call of keyPress, made the rest of the keyPresses work and the remaining keyPresses not work.

I'm confused. Can somebody tell me when is the proper time to use keyRelease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTest::keyPress` simulates an user pressing a key, while `QTest::keyRelease` simulates an user releasing a key.

After you press a key you should release it, otherwise it's like if the key is still pressed. Yes, you need to call `QTest::keyRelease` after any `QTest::keyPress` call.